# Soluble(solvable) and nilpotent groups

Tags: finite-groups, solvable-groups

**Defn 1.1.** Let $\gamma _{0}(G)=G$, and $\gamma _{c}(G)=[\gamma _{c-1}(G),G]$ for $c\geq 1$. The **lower central series** of $G$ is a chain of subgroups of $G$:
$$G=\gamma_0(G) \geq \gamma_1(G) \geq \cdots \geq \gamma_{c}(G)=1,$$
where the least such $c$ is called the **nilpotency class of $G$.**

**Defn 1.2.** Let $G^{(0)}=G$, and $G^{(d)}=[G^{(d-1)},G^{(d-1)}]$ for $d\geq 1$. The **derived series** of $G$ is a chain of subgroups of $G$:
$$G=G^{(0)}\geq G^{(1)}\geq \cdots \geq G^{(d)}=1,$$
where the least such $d$ is called the **derived length of $G$.**

**Defn 2.1.** A group $G$ is **nilpotent** if $\gamma _{c}(G)=1$ for some $c\geq 0$.

**Defn 2.2.** A group $G$ is **soluble(solvable)** if $G^{(d)}=1$ for some $d\geq 0$.

It follows from the definitions that $\gamma_1(G)=[G,G]=G^{(1)}$.  On the other hand, $\gamma_2(G)=[\gamma_1(G),G]=[[G,G],G]=[\gamma_1(G),G]$ while $G^{(2)}=[G^{(1)},G^{(1)}]=[\gamma_1(G),\gamma_1(G)]$.

My questions are as follows:

1. We know that $G^{(i)}$ is a subgroup of $\gamma_i(G)$ for all $i$. How can we use it to show that every nilpotent group is solvable?
2. What are the examples of soluble groups that are not nilpotent?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: I got it. I actually want to say how to use 1 to show that every nilpotent group is solvable. Let me edit the question.

Comment: 2. $S_3$ is solvable, but not nilpotent (because of trivial centre).

Comment: @ Dietrich, thanks.

Comment: Show that $G^{(i)}\le\gamma_{f(i)}(G)$ for a suitable (non-decreasing) function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

As you say you know $\;G^i\le\gamma_i\;$, if $\;G\;$ is nilpotent there exists $\;c\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. $\;\gamma_c=1\;$ , and this means $\;G^c\le\gamma_c=1\implies G^c=1\;$ , which means $\;G\;$ is soluble...

OTOH, I think it'd be easier to observe that any central series (say, as the lower central or the upper central series) is **always** abelian...

Comment: @ Timbuc, thanks a lot. I am now ok!